# Woocommerce product search result page layout

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript

I am creating a custom search bar with a category dropdown in my woo-commerce site so how do I fetch the exact design(HTML, CSS) of products in my search result as I am getting through shortcodes like [product], etc. Do I need to make Custom Search Results Template? Is there any way to fetch the design that woocommerce shortcodes call? can I call that exact design in my code?